# Create custom frame in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, frame

[image]

I have to create a frame like in the attached photo ,the thing is that it has to be adaptable as it will contain labels/texts , also it should have elevation and shadow .
All that is easily doable with a frame , the problem is the little speech thing , i can't find a way to make it .

maybe someone has an idea to start with .
thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can binding the **Height** and **Width** of the frame with its child element (like label).

#### in code behind

```
public class SizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value + 20.0); // you can set the logic of height and width here  
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:SizeConverter x:Key="SizeConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Frame CornerRadius="10" WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentLabel}, Path=Width,Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter} ,Mode=OneWay}" MinimumHeightRequest="100" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentLabel}, Path=Height,Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter} ,Mode=OneWay}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Padding="10" >
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label x:Name="contentLabel"  BackgroundColor="LightGray" Text="xxx" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but the problem is how to do the ui of the little arrow in the frame

Comment: It seems you want to create a chat frame?

Comment: Yes it's a look like

Comment: You can use some third party library from nuget . It will be a little complex if you implement it by yourself.

Comment: have you any example please ?

Comment: thank you , but it's not what i need , my only problem is the UI of the frame

Comment: You can create an image like it and set it to the background of `Label` (for example you can put them in the same cell of grid).